# Convert string to a bash date on OSX and check if older than 90 days

Tags: arrays, string, bash, macos, date

I am trying to convert the following "timestamp" string to a date within bash on OSX. I want to be able to calculate wether the date is older than 90 days old.

```
<------- hg-test-onprem-connector ------>>>
[
 {
"digest": "sha256:6607adac160984fe08f4578b0894c0640647e28cfb712564621667ee9812938c",
"tags": [],
"timestamp": "2019-02-28T14:49:28.4658512Z"
```

I have so far found out how to do convert a date in bash (osx) but unsure how to convert this specific date into that format.

```sh
CURR_DATE=$(date +”%d%m%Y”)
echo ‘Current date: ‘$CURR_DATE

# Find the date 90 days ago – For OSX bash:
DELETION_DATE=$(date -v-90d +”%d%m%Y”)
echo ‘Previous date: ‘$DELETION_DATE
```

any suggestions will help greatly.

Answer (score 4):

I think the first problem is that the OSX date command doesn't support decimal fractions, so it needs to be fixed before you can covert it into a date.

Here's my solution:

```
FIXED_TIMESTAMP=$(echo "2019-02-28T14:49:28.4658512Z" | sed s/\\.[0-9]*//g)
TIMESTAMP_AS_DATE=$(date -jf "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" $FIXED_TIMESTAMP +%d%m%Y)
echo ‘Timestamp date: ‘$TIMESTAMP_AS_DATE
```

The first line of the above code uses sed to strip out the decimal fractions of the second component.  On the second line we then convert it into the format you are currently using for your other variables using an ISO8601 compatible formatting string to read in the fixed timestamp.

That should return you a numeric value in line with the other numeric values you have.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to calculate whether the *[ "timestamp" ]* date is older than 90 days old.

#### Solution

This can be achieved as follows on OSX using the built-in `date` utility:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

timestamp=2019-02-28T14:49:28.4658512Z

epoch_timestamp=$(date -jf "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" "${timestamp%%.*}Z" "+%s")
epoch_now=$(date "+%s")

days_diff=$(( (epoch_now - epoch_timestamp) / (24*3600) ))

# Testing...
if (( days_diff > 90 )); then
  echo "${timestamp} is greater than 90 days old."
else
  echo "${timestamp} is less than, or equal to 90 days old."
fi
```

---

#### Explanation

The following will hopefully help provide a better understanding of some of the constituent parts in the script above.

- On line five we convert the given `timestamp` value, i.e. `2019-02-28T14:49:28.4658512Z`, to [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) time and assign the result to a variable named `epoch_timestamp`.

  ```sh
  epoch_timestamp=$(date -jf "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" "${timestamp%%.*}Z" "+%s")
  ```

  The part that reads `"${timestamp%%.*}Z"` utilizes [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove the substring after the first dot character (`.`), including the first dot character itself. This effectively removes the `.4658512Z` substring from your timestamp, i.e. the *microseconds* and `Z`. We do this because the mac OSX built-in `date` utility cannot resolve *microseconds*. The trailing `Z` part exists to reinstate the `Z` which was previously deleted.
- On line six we also convert the the current date/time to Epoch time, and assign the result to a variable named `epoch_now`:

  ```sh
  epoch_now=$(date "+%s")
  ```
- On line eight we calculate the *number of days* difference between the `epoch_now` and `epoch_timestamp` values and assign the result to a variable named `days_diff`:

  ```sh
  days_diff=$(( (epoch_now - epoch_timestamp) / (24*3600) ))
  ```

---

#### Note:

If you are also wanting to programmatically obtain the `timestamp` value from the JSON data, then consider utilizing a command-line JSON processor such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) or [JSON Tool](https://trentm.com/json/).

For instance; using *JSON Tool* you could read the contents of the JSON file (as given in your question) and assign the `timestamp` value to a variable named `timestamp`:

```
timestamp=$(json -a timestamp <~/Desktop/path/to/file.json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does OSX date support `-d` (`--date`)?

The following works for me:

```
    date -d "2019-02-28T14:49:28.4658512Z" +"%d%m%Y"
```

However, my `date` does not support `-v`.

I don't know how to calculate 90 days but I find `%Y%m%d` more useful to compare dates as numeric compare works for this format.

Comment: The -d flag does not work on OSX unless you download the GNU core utilities, i do not want to do this as it is a shared device.

Comment: BSD `date` is actually a little nicer than GNU `date` in this respect. Instead of relying on an underdocumented "natural language" representation for arguments with the `-d` option, you specify *exactly* what you mean with the `-f` option. `date -jf "%FT%T" 2019-02-28T14:49:28 +%d%m%Y` outputs `28022109`.